# Glue to withstand high temperatures

Tags: wood, adhesive, heat

I want to glue pieces of wood to a sheet of a plastic-like material. This will then be placed in the oven at 200 degrees celsius. Which glue should I use?

Comment: wood will tend to *burn* at that temperature, or at least emit flammable gasses, ...

Comment: 200*C is less than 400*F. Most wood won't burn that low.

Comment: Some dry woods will ignite at as low as 451F (wikipedia but SE's not taking this comment with the link) 200C = 392F.  Just 60 degrees to go, the wood may be emitting gasses at 200C.  The plastic is also a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Silicone adhesive will bond to wood and many plastics (and most things).  Most silicone will deal with high temperatures, but there is silicone designed for very high temperatures (for engine gaskets, fireplaces, etc.).  You can find it at auto supply stores, Harbor Freight, most hardware stores, etc.  Examples:

- https://www.harborfreight.com/3-oz-rtv-silicone-red-90026.html
- http://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-High-Temp-Black-Silicone-Gasket?N=5002385+3292638826&rt=rud
- https://www.permatex.com/products/gasketing/gasket-makers/permatex-high-temp-red-rtv-silicone-gasket/
- [https://www.amazon.com/Rutland-500-Degree-Silicone-10-3-Ounce-Cartridge/dp/B000DZBLNC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000DZBLNC)